# Parsing strings recursively

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract information out of a string - a fortran formatting string to be specific. The string is formatted like:

```
F8.3, I5, 3(5X, 2(A20,F10.3)), 'XXX'
```

with formatting fields delimited by "," and formatting groups inside brackets, with the number in front of the brackets indicating how many consecutive times the formatting pattern is repeated. So, the string above expands to:

```
F8.3, I5, 5X, A20,F10.3, A20,F10.3, 5X, A20,F10.3, A20,F10.3, 5X, A20,F10.3, A20,F10.3, 'XXX'
```

I am trying to make something in C# that will expand a string that conforms to that pattern. I have started going about it with lots of switch and if statements, but am wondering if I am not going about it the wrong way?

I was basically wondering if some Regex wizzard thinks that Regular expressions can do this in one neat-fell swoop? I know nothing about regular expressions, but if this could solve my problem I am considering putting in some time to learn how to use them... on the other hand if regular expressions can't sort this out then I'd rather spend my time looking at another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a recusive method like the example below( not tested ):

```
ResultData Parse(String value, ref Int32 index)
{
    ResultData result = new ResultData();
    Index startIndex = index; // Used to get substrings

    while (index < value.Length) 
    {
        Char current = value[index];

        if (current == '(')
        {
            index++;
            result.Add(Parse(value, ref index));
            startIndex = index;
            continue;
        }
        if (current == ')')
        {
            // Push last result
           index++;
           return result;
        }

        // Process all other chars here
    }

    // We can't find the closing bracket
    throw new Exception("String is not valid");
}
```

You maybe need to modify some parts of the code, but this method have i used when writing a simple compiler. Although it's not completed, just a example.

Comment: I ended up doing something like you suggested and it worked. It is not recursive though, but works from the highest level of nesting down to the lowest. Seems to work, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be doable with Regex :) 
I've expanded my previous example and it test nicely with your example.

```
// regex to match the inner most patterns of n(X) and capture the values of n and X.
private static readonly Regex matcher = new Regex(@"(\d+)\(([^(]*?)\)", RegexOptions.None);

// create new string by repeating X n times, separated with ','
private static string Join(Match m)
{
    var n = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value); // get value of n
    var x = m.Groups[2].Value; // get value of X
    return String.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat(x, n));
}

// expand the string by recursively replacing the innermost values of n(X).
private static string Expand(string text)
{
    var s = matcher.Replace(text, Join);
    return (matcher.IsMatch(s)) ? Expand(s) : s;
}

// parse a string for occurenses of n(X) pattern and expand then.
// return the string as a tokenized array.
public static string[] Parse(string text)
{
    // Check that the number of parantheses is even.
    if (text.Sum(c => (c == '(' || c == ')') ? 1 : 0) % 2 == 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("The string contains an odd number of parantheses.");

    return Expand(text).Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't do anything at all. The way of the regex is mysterious and impenetrable.

Comment: I only just saw that you updated this. I just tried it out and although it works fine with the example I gave it failed with something else: 6F9.3, 2I9, 2(F9.4, 3(I2, (F8.3))), 4(I2, F10.5). I know there is a slight mistake in there because the F8.3 does not have a coefficient, but I need the algorithm to be at least robust enough to cope with that situation as well... It would have been nice to do this with regex, but I've done it with a couple of straight code methods and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest using a recursive function instead.  Every time you hit an opening parenthesis, call the function again to parse that part.  I'm not sure if you can use a regex to match a recursive data structure.

(**Edit**: Removed incorrect regex)

Comment: this would match `3(...(...)`, no?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited my answer to remove the incorrect regex.  I've read that regexes aren't really a good tool to match recursive structures. Maybe instead of a regex, write a function that simply examines the string character by character and counts parentheses. Once the number of closing parentheses matches the number of opening parentheses, you have your substring.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up rewriting this today. It turns out that this can be done in one single method:

```
private static string ExpandBrackets(string Format)
    {
        int maxLevel = CountNesting(Format);

        for (int currentLevel = maxLevel; currentLevel > 0; currentLevel--)
        {
            int level = 0;
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Format.Length; i++)
            {
                char thisChar = Format[i];
                switch (Format[i])
                {
                    case '(':
                        level++;
                        if (level == currentLevel)
                        {
                            string group = string.Empty;
                            int repeat = 0;

                            /// Isolate the number of repeats if any
                            /// If there are 0 repeats the set to 1 so group will be replaced by itself with the brackets removed
                            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                            {
                                char c = Format[j];
                                if (c == ',')
                                {
                                    start = j + 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                                if (char.IsDigit(c))
                                    repeat = int.Parse(c + (repeat != 0 ? repeat.ToString() : string.Empty));
                                else
                                    throw new Exception("Non-numeric character " + c + " found in front of the brackets");
                            }
                            if (repeat == 0)
                                repeat = 1;

                            /// Isolate the format group
                            /// Parse until the first closing bracket. Level is decremented as this effectively takes us down one level
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < Format.Length; j++)
                            {
                                char c = Format[j];
                                if (c == ')')
                                {
                                    level--;
                                    end = j;
                                    break;
                                }
                                group += c;
                            }

                            /// Substitute the expanded group for the original group in the format string
                            /// If the group is empty then just remove it from the string
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(group))
                            {
                                Format = Format.Remove(start - 1, end - start + 2);
                                i = start;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string repeatedGroup = RepeatString(group, repeat);
                                Format = Format.Remove(start, end - start + 1).Insert(start, repeatedGroup);
                                i = start + repeatedGroup.Length - 1;
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case ')':
                        level--;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return Format;
    }
```

`CountNesting()` returns the highest level of bracket nesting in the format statement, but could be passed in as a parameter to the method. `RepeatString()` just repeats a string the specified number of times and substitutes it for the bracketed group in the format string.